# What is input.customer in Shopify-api-node?

Tags: node.js, api, shopify, shopify-app

I am using [MONEI/Shopify-api-node](https://github.com/MONEI/Shopify-api-node) for creating app in Shopify. I have gone through there test cases for creating Customer [Shopify-api-node/test/customer.test.js](https://github.com/MONEI/Shopify-api-node/blob/master/test/customer.test.js)I just want Format Param for creating customer.When user sign up with email and contact number, I want customer to be created with email and number at my store admin.I just want format param like [Format of params for webhook.create](https://github.com/MONEI/Shopify-api-node/issues/118)

If anyone has ever created customer please drop the required param here.
Also please check my code whether is it correct way to create customer or not thanks.

```
const createCustomer = function(shopDomain, accessToken, customer) {
  const shopName=shopDomain.replace('.myshopify.com','');
  const shopify = new ShopifyAPIClient({ shopName: shopName, accessToken: accessToken });

shopify.customer.create(customer).then(
   response => console.log(`customer ${customer.url}  created`),
   err => console.log(`Error creating customer ${customer.url} ${JSON.stringify(err.response.body)}`)
);

}
```

function call

```
afterAuth(request, response) {
    const { session: { accessToken, shop } } = request;

      createCustomer(shop,accessToken,{
        topic: 'admin/customers',
        address: `${SHOPIFY_APP_HOST}/admin/customers`,
      });

    return response.redirect('/');
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer from Here.[What is input.customer for customer.create and customer.update ?](https://github.com/MONEI/Shopify-api-node/issues/229)